# I want to set local notification in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I m new to objective-c, i want to set local notification in my app.

App should be work with both IOS 8 and all less than IOS 8 version.

please help me with detail code.

Comment: Start reading the Apple documentation on [About Local Notifications and Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Comment: Have you googled it atleast?

Comment: i have seen that document but i cant understand what to do fro coding side

Comment: i have put this code in appdelagate.m 
if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)) {
        if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            
            
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
            
        }
    }else{   
    }
 but i dont know what to do in else part

Comment: Check [this](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=292) and [this](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    #end
}
```

and you fire a local notification like this:

```
- (void)showNotificationWithMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = message;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: @sejalthesiya yes for sure. Please try and let me know.

Comment: @sejalthesiya make sure that you are calling this function one time. If this function is called two times then the notification will be registered two times and will show two times.

Comment: i m calling only one time.can i use cancelAllLocalNotifications before creating notifications?

Comment: try that and let me know

Comment: still coming 2 times.

Comment: @sejalthesiya please share the code snippet if possible

Comment: see below i have share it

Comment: i have find that didReceiveLocalNotification called 2 time per notification

Comment: @sejalthesiya I figured it out from the code you provided. You are scheduling the notification twice. This line [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; is used two times.

Comment: inner for loop will run two time if reminder set for two day or two different time in one day...

Comment: @sejalthesiya You have to check the allDate which you are setting it to fireDate may be they are same for both the notifications.

Comment: i uninstall app from simulater.after reinstallion i have set reminder for time in one day only but still getting twi time notification. i put breakpoint on [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification].this line run only one time.please help me i dont know how to fix this problem

Comment: @sejalthesiya we can chat may be to solve this problem

Comment: @sejalthesiya you don't have enough reputation to chat on stackoverflow

Comment: @sejalthesiya let me know if there is any other way to communicate.